# Unknown Padding on Containing Element

Tags: html, css

There is what appears to be a 2px bottom padding on the image to the containing element. I am able to resolve this by removing the z-index. I need the z-index arrangement however to provide an inset box shadow on the image.

It can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/JkLAP/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just add `.photo{display:block}`

**demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/JkLAP/2/

Comment: Thank you. I can't believe that flew over my head.